# Saving information in controller symfony relation ManyToMany HELPPPPP

Tags: symfony, controller, doctrine

Hi I need to save information in my db, what I mean is, how to persist when the relationship is manytomany, I am doing like this but it doesn't work!...I will put some code of entity Menu.

```
     /** Agrega nuevo menù
         *
         * @Route("/save", name="admin_menu_save")
         * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
         * @param Request $request
         * @return Response
         */
        public function saveAction(Request $request)
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $fecha_menu = $request->get('fecha');
            $fecha_comprar = $request->get('fechacomprado');
            $fecha_vencimiento = $request->get('fechavencimiento');
            $alimentos = $request->get('select_alimentos');
            $a = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Alimento')->findBy($alimentos);
            $menu = new Menu();
            $menu->setFecha(new \DateTime($fecha_menu));
            $menu->setFechacomprar(new \DateTime($fecha_comprar));
            $menu->setFechavence(new \DateTime($fecha_vencimiento));
            $menu->setPrecio(6);
            $menu->addAlimento($a);
            $em->persist($menu);
            $em->flush();
            return new Response('Guardado OK');
        }
 //Menu Entity Definition (Just the necessary code):

       /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Alimento", inversedBy="menu")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="alimento_menu",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="menu_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="alimento_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $alimento;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->alimento = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Add alimento
     *
     * @param \AdminBundle\Entity\Alimento $alimento
     *
     * @return Menu
     */
    public function addAlimento(Alimento $alimento)
    {
        $this->alimento[] = $alimento;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove alimento
     *
     * @param \AdminBundle\Entity\Alimento $alimento
     */
    public function removeAlimento(Alimento $alimento)
    {
        $this->alimento->removeElement($alimento);
    }


    /**
     * Get alimento
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getAlimento()
    {
        return $this->alimento;
    }

}
```

I have not experience working with manytomany relations, I hope to solve this problem, that´s show very good, but I don´t know how to save,edit or remove in that manytomany table!....

Comment: Post your `Menu` entity definition

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Is it exception? Is data not saved?

Comment: Excepcion:  Unrecognized field: 0

Comment: Use:  `$this->alimento->add($alimento)` not the: `$this->alimento[]=...`.

Comment: Not working!:..maybe I have the problems in my controller!....someone help?

Comment: In addAllimento function add this :
$alimento->setMenu($this);

Answer (score 1):

First, this bit seems weird.

```
$alimentos = $request->get('select_alimentos');
$a = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Alimento')->findBy($alimentos);
```

Doctrine findBy takes an array with the entity field as a key and the specific entity value as the value. Like this:

```
$em-getRepository('AdminBundle:Alimento')->findBy(['id' => $id]);
```

If that's how your `$alimentos` variable is structured, that's fine. It just looks strange.

If this is a bi-directional relationship, you have to update both entities. So your controller code is like:

```
$a = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Alimento')->findBy($alimentos);
$menu = new Menu();

// -- more code ---//

$menu->addAlimento($a);
$a->addMenu($menu);
$em->persist($menu);
$em->flush();
```

[Check this documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html).

Answer (score -1):

I just realized what was...This was my solution:

```
foreach ($alimentos as $item) {
            $a = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Alimento')->find($item);
            $menu->addAlimento($a);
        }
```

And of course later I persist menu.

Comment: Why don't you use `->findById($alimentos);`? When you're using a repository method in a loop, it should ring a bell.

Comment: No, it doesn´t work, because you need an instance of that class, not the id in fact

Comment: No, you don't. FindById takes an array with id's.